# Flip zeros (with probability alpha) and ones (with a probability beta) of a numpy array?

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm, numpy, time-complexity, numpy-ndarray

I am working with a numpy array A of size 15000*15000.I want to flip zeros of this array with a probability alpha and ones of this array with a probability beta.Is there a better way to this?

```
    cn=0
    n=A.shape[0]
    ans=np.zeros((n,n))
    for i in A:
        zeros=np.where(i==0)[0]
        ones=np.where(i==1)[0]
        fl_zeros=list(np.random.choice(zeros,round(len(zeros)*alpha),replace=False))
        fl_ones=list(np.random.choice(ones,round(len(ones)*beta),replace=False))
        ind=np.array(fl_zeros+fl_ones).astype(np.int32)
        tmp=np.zeros(n)
        np.put_along_axis(tmp,ind,1.0,axis=0)
        ans[cn]=np.logical_xor(i,tmp)
        cn+=1
```

Comment: What is the expected output, when I sampled A with [0, 1] with equal probability, and apply your algorithm with alpha = 0.8, beta =0.2 the mean value of `ans` was around 0.16. I was anticipating  `mean(ans) > 0.5` for these values

Comment: The usual reading of your title calls for independent decisions for each matrix entry, but your code flips a specific number of entries, which is not independent. Which is it?

Comment: @itamarkanter the numpy array that I have is very sparse , in total 47k edges and if I flip both ones and zeros with same probability then I will end up with around huge number of ones which is not desired . So I need existing ones to be flipped with lets say 0.7 probability and zeros with 0.001 probability so that the sparsity of the matrix is not too different before and after flipping.Thanks in advance.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat I flip alpha protion of total zeros and beta porion of toal ones randomly in every row ,so every flip is independent right? Please correct me if I am wrong?Thanks in advance.

Comment: No -- conditioned on flipping the first zero, the remaining zeros are less likely to flip. Similarly, conditioned on not flipping the first zero, the remaining zeros are more likely to flip. As a degenerate example, take alpha = beta = 0.5 and a matrix [[0,0],[0,0]]. If the flips were independent you'd get a random matrix, whereas controlling the count in each row can only yield one of the matrices [[1,0],[1,0]], [[1,0],[0,1]], [[0,1],[1,0]], [[0,1],[0,1]].